# MYSQL Select group by order by

Tags: mysql, sql, select

i have this table:

**messages**

```sql
/*Table structure for table `messages` */

CREATE TABLE `messages` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fromperson` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `sent` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `msgread` int(2) DEFAULT 0,
  `content` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `toperson` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `route` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=75508 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

/*Data for the table `messages` */

insert  into `messages`(`id`,`fromperson`,`sent`,`msgread`,`content`,`toperson`,`route`) values 
(75477,'jaritje','2020-07-31 11:47:59.000000',1,'helemaal niks :)','anaisje',0),
(75478,'jaritje','2020-07-31 11:48:25.000000',1,'wdj','anaisje',1),
(75479,'jaritje','2020-05-25 12:57:27.000000',1,'cv','anaisje',0),
(75501,'jaritje','2020-05-25 13:38:31.000000',1,'gmj*','anaisje',1),
(75502,'jaritje','2020-05-25 13:38:48.000000',1,'gm','anaisje',1),
(75503,'jaritje','2020-05-26 16:53:27.000000',1,'hgh','anaisje',0),
(75504,'jaritje','2020-05-26 17:05:27.000000',1,'hey\r\n','anaisje',1),
(75505,'jaritje','2020-05-26 18:14:03.000000',1,'hallo','anaisje',0),
(75507,'jaritje','2020-07-22 12:57:27.000000',1,'TEST   ','saartje',1);
```

Now i want to select every most recent message with every person.
So the most recent message with "anaisje" and with "saartje".

So i want the rows with id 75478 and 75507.

I read on the internet that

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY sent DESC) AS person WHERE fromperson = ?
```

should work, but it doesn't for me...

Anyone can help me with this?
Thanks in advance,

Jari

Comment: `FIRST_VALUE(message) OVER (PARTITION BY person ORDER BY timestamp DESC)`

Comment: what do you mean with that?

Comment: This is an expression which may solve your task. If you want more detailed answer then replace the photo with CREATE TABLE script, INSERT INTO script with some sample data, show desired output for this data, and ask moderators for the question reopening.

Comment: How may i ask moderators for the question reopening? I added the create table and insert into scripts. Thanks in advance

Comment: I do not see *desired output for this data*. How someone can help if he doesn't know what result is needed?

Comment: I added the desired output.

Comment: Now wait until needed votes amount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the most recent row of data by sender and receiver, you can use a self join as follows:

```
select * 
from messages msg
where sent = (select max(sent) 
              from messages msg_
              where msg_.fromperson = msg.fromperson
               and msg_.toperson = msg.toperson)
```

[See how it works in this Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)